# Expected ')' in javascript using IE browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have created a function for calculating EMI in javascript. But IE is showing some error that I mentioned in the title. Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

```js
function calculateEmi(error = false) {
    var freemonth = ($('#offers option:selected').data('emi')) ? $('#offers option:selected').data('emi') : 0;
    var main = $('.bank-cal.active')
    var downpayment = main.find('.js-inputDownpayment').val()
    var emimonths = main.find('.js-inputTenure').val()
    var intrestper = (main.find('.js-inputTenure').data('percantage') / 12) * (emimonths - freemonth)

    var price = parseInt($('#variation option:selected').data('price'));
    $('.adons-radio:checked').each(function() {
        price += parseInt($(this).data('price'));
    })
    trade = 0;
    if (
        localStorage.getItem('tradeprcie') &&
        $('.tradein-checkbox').is(':checked') &&
        localStorage.getItem('tab') != '#bymodel' && localStorage.getItem('trade')
    ) {
        trade = localStorage.getItem('tradeprcie');
        trade = trade - ((downpayment / 100) * price);
        if (trade < 0) {
            trade = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `function calculateEmi(error = false)` -> using default parameters is not valid for IE. You have to do it the old way and have `error = error !== undefined ? error : false` in the body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function calculateEmi(error = false) {
  ...
}
```

From [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters), we can see that using the above method to set default parameter is ES6/ES2015 syntax, which is not supported in IE browser.

To set the default parameters in IE browser, we could use the following code:

```
function calculateEmi(error) {
  error = typeof error !== 'undefined' ? error : "false"; 
  ...
}
```